# Google map location update

Tags: android

Used FusedlocationApi to receive location update fine. Mobile placed on desk, not moving anywhere, but location has been changed every time getting the location update. I draw the polyline according to the receive location.
How to fix this?

Comment: are you using coarse location as well?

Comment: Yes i have used.

Comment: coarse location updates will fetch loaction from near by cellular towers if you want pin point location i will suggest to remove coarse location and only take location updates using GPS

Answer (score 0):

```
float[] results = new float[1];

Location.distanceBetween(preLatitude, preLongitude, latitude, longitude, results);

float distanceInMeters = results[0];

boolean isWithinRadius50m = distanceInMeters > 
Constants.UPDATE_LOCATION_DISTANCE_CHECK_METER;

if (isWithinRadius50m == true) {

//perform your opration here
}
```

Using this code you can check radius code if your distance is move according meter check after that you can perform your functionality .